# How can I render a TokBox Screen Share stream in aspectFit

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

I have a TokBox iOS app that renders a Screen Share stream for the user. The video stream is cropped if it is larger than the view. It is set by default to an aspect FILL.

I cannot find a way to change this to aspect FIT. Does anyone know if this is possible on TokBox iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my case, this will do the trick, `self.subscriber` is an instance of `OTSubscriber`:

```
self.subscriber.viewScaleBehavior = OTVideoViewScaleBehaviorFit;;
```

You can also check this out: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ios/reference/Constants/OTVideoViewScaleBehavior.html

Comment: Thank you! Why couldn't I find this anywhere? The TokBox documentation said this was impossible on iOS without using a custom renderer. I nearly built one!

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Which docs said that? But I normally just check the docs with their iOS SDK. I also check out the iOS sample repo: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk-samples